# Optimize OrderBy Generic Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Here is my OrderBy method which includes concatenated column names.
Can this be achieved more efficiently?

```
public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<SortationDto> sortations)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    sortations.ForEach(s =>
    {
        Expression value = null;
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item");

        // if sortation is a concatenation of two columns
        if (s.Concatenated.Count > 0)
        {
            Expression concat = null;
            s.Concatenated.ForEach(c =>
            {
                //get first property
                value = c.Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);

                //if first property add as initial property
                if (concat == null)
                {
                    concat = value;
                }
                else //else concatenate with first property
                {
                    MethodInfo concatMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
                    value = Expression.Call(concatMethod, concat, Expression.Constant(" "), value);
                }
            });
        }
        else //else use one and only property
        {
            value = s.Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        }

        //build lambda expression
        LambdaExpression predicate = Expression.Lambda(value, parameter);

        //define orderby method name based on current iteration of sortations
        string methodName = (sortations.IndexOf(s) == 0 ? "Order" : "Then") + (s.Direction == "asc" ? "By" : "ByDescending");

        //call method
        MethodCallExpression orderBy = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { query.ElementType, value.Type }, query.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));

        //add final expression to query
        query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderBy);
    });

    return query;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of sorting concatenations when you're already supporting sorting by multiple columns?

Comment: Good point! I'll rework this method.

Answer (score 1):

Removed unnecessary concatenation.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<SortationDto> sortations)
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    List<SortationDto> combined = sortations.Where(s => s.Concatenated.Count == 0).Union(sortations.SelectMany(so => so.Concatenated)).ToList();

    combined.ForEach(s =>
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item");
        Expression value = s.Column.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        LambdaExpression predicate = Expression.Lambda(value, parameter);

        string methodName = (combined.IndexOf(s) == 0 ? "Order" : "Then") + (s.Direction == "asc" ? "By" : "ByDescending");
        MethodCallExpression orderBy = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { query.ElementType, value.Type }, query.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));             
        query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderBy);
    });

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your code! Works like a charm. Ended up using it with some adjustments and the extension method below. I pass the Sort objects in so that any parsing is done outside (separate the concern a bit).

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplySort<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, params Sort[] sorts)
    {
        if (sorts == null)
            return query;
        var applicableSorts = sorts.Where(s => s != null);
        if (!applicableSorts.Any())
            return query;
        applicableSorts
            .Select((item, index) => new { Index = index, item.PropertyName, item.Direction })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(sort =>
            {
                ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "entity");
                var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, sort.PropertyName);
                var sortPredicate = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, parameterExpression);

                string methodName = (sort.Index == 0 ? "Order" : "Then") + (sort.Direction == OrderDirection.Ascending ? "By" : "ByDescending");
                MethodCallExpression orderBy = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new Type[] { query.ElementType, propertyExpression.Type }, query.Expression, Expression.Quote(sortPredicate));
                query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(orderBy);
            });

        return query;
    }
```